# Return unique values from _.map()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have grouped a collection of data using underscore's groupBy, however when I map the data that was grouped, I am getting duplicates:

```js
var data = [];
for (var i = 1; i < (allTextLines.length - 1); i++){
    var obj = {};
    var allTextLine = allTextLines[i].split(',');
    obj["date"] = allTextLine[headerColumnIndexMap[requiredHeaders[1]]];
    obj["servingTime"] = allTextLine[headerColumnIndexMap[requiredHeaders[2]]];
    obj["replacement"] = allTextLine[headerColumnIndexMap[requiredHeaders[3]]];
    obj["fullname"] = allTextLine[headerColumnIndexMap[requiredHeaders[4]]];
    obj["center"] = allTextLine[headerColumnIndexMap[requiredHeaders[5]]];
    obj["products"] = allTextLine[headerColumnIndexMap[requiredHeaders[6]]];


    data.push(obj);

}


var groups = _.groupBy(data, function(v){
                    return [v.date, v.servingTime, v.replacement];
                });

var grouped = _.map(groups, function(group){
                    return {
                        date : group[0].date,
                        servingTime : group[0].servingTime,
                        replacement : group[0].replacement,
                        children: _.map(group, function(f){
                            return [f.fullname, f.center];
                        }),
                        products: _.map(group, 'products'),
                        units : _.map(group, 'fullname').length

                    };
                });
```

Question is how do I remove duplicates from the results of children and products? I have tried chaining and using .unique().value(), but it was not working...

```js
var grouped = _.map(groups, function(group){
                    return {
                        date : group[0].date,
                        servingTime : group[0].servingTime,
                        replacement : group[0].replacement,
                        children: _.chain(group).map(group, function(f){
                            return [f.fullname, f.center];
                        }).uniq().value(),
                        products: _.map(group, 'products'),
                        units : _.map(group, 'fullname').length

                    };
                });
```

Here is the result that is shown in the debugger:

[image]

Comment: If you can use es6 `Set` then `Array.from(new Set(<array to dedup>))` works, but its not the most efficient answer possible.

Comment: Set is part of the language. no library needed! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: there should be a method in underscore that does this...

Comment: There is, `.uniq()`, which should work but you mentioned that you had tried it and I didn't want to recommend re-doing the same thing.

Comment: Here's an example just in case https://jsfiddle.net/Sammons/qvmn8sg0/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `Set` - it doesn't allow duplicates:

```
products: Array.from(new Set(_.map(group, "products"))),
```

Read more about `Set` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Alternatively, add a `filter` to the end of your `_.map`:

```
products: _.map(groups, "products").filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) == i),
```

Comment: No problem @AlanJudi, always glad to help.